# Don't get any public folder when deployment in svelte kit app

Tags: tomcat, deployment, svelte, sveltekit

I develop a svelte kit app and go to deploy using "npm run build". "npm run build" command works correctly and successful. But it didn't make any public folder for deployment. can you guys have any idea about that issue.